# HashMap<Node, Integer> get returns null even when hashcode() is the same

Tags: java, hash, nullpointerexception, hashmap, hashtable

I have a custom class Node:

```
public static class Node{

    int _id;
    // adjacent node and its cost
    HashMap<Node, Integer> _adjList = new HashMap<>();

    public Node(int id){
        _id = id;
    }

    public boolean equals(Node n) {
        if (n == null)
            return false;
        return _id == n._id;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
            return _id;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "("+_id+")";
    }

}//Node
```

I use it as a key to the `HashMap<Node, Integer> costs`, where for a given node, there is a cost of getting to the node associated with it. 
Later in the program, I have `costs` filled with values:

```
{(1)=0, (2)=24, (3)=3, (4)=15}
```

Then, later in the code, when I query `costs` like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= g.nNodes; ++i){
            Node tempNode = new Node(i);
            Integer cost = currentPathCosts.get(tempNode);
            System.out.println("cost:"+cost);
        }
```

I get

```
null
null
null
```

as the output.
What is wrong? The `hashcode()` of the Nodes with the same `_id` should be the same..Am I missing something?

---

**UPDATE:**

I was missing **Node other = (Node)n;** in the equals() method.
the way to override hashcode() and equals() that worked for me:

```
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object n) {
            if (n == null)
                return false;
            Node other = (Node)n;
            return _id == other._id;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
                return _id;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `@Override` annotation on your `equals()` method, as you should always do when you want to override a method, and the compiler will tell you what the problem is. (Do the same for hashCode, while you're at it).

You're not overriding `Object.equals()`. You're defining a different, overloaded `equals()` method.